# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'export_job'

Tags: django, django-import-export, django-import-export-celery

I am implementing an export function with `django-import-export-celery` and the [instructions](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export-celery/#:%7E:text=your%20Winners%20table.-,Setting%20up%20exports,-As%20with%20imports)
are only three steps. I followed all of them, and when I try to do an export, it gives me an error on the celery process:

[image]

This is what my code looks like:

```
class Issuer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False,)

    @classmethod
    def export_resource_classes(cls):
        return {
            "Issuers": ("Issuers resource", IssuerResource),
        }


class IssuerResource(ModelResource):
    def ready(self):
        class Meta:
            model = apps.get_model('crowdfunding.Issuer')
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Added stack trace as text.

```
[2022-03-07 05:02:21,061: INFO/MainProcess] Task py_scripts.background_check.export_sdn_results[2ca53746-c134-4bb5-a35b-ccd27e1a845d] succeeded in 0.0s: None
[2022-03-07 05:28:01,005: INFO/MainProcess] Task import_export_celery.tasks.run_export_job[bcc37ee4-258e-4a98-881d-8b7ccc9487c4] received
[2022-03-07 05:28:01,006: INFO/MainProcess] import_export_celery.tasks.run_export_job[bcc37ee4-258e-4a98-881d-8b7ccc9487c4]: Exporting 1
[2022-03-07 05:28:01,082: ERROR/MainProcess] Task import_export_celery.tasks.run_export_job[bcc37ee4-258e-4a98-881d-8b7ccc9487c4] raised unexpected: TypeError("Resource.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'export_job'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\celery.py", line 200, in _inner
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\_compat.py", line 54, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\celery.py", line 195, in _inner
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export_celery\tasks.py", line 219, in run_export_job
    resource = Resource(export_job=export_job)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export_celery\tasks.py", line 207, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Resource.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'export_job'
```

**UPDATE 2**: Added new `ModelResource` and stack trace, with updated django-import-export-celery version 1.1.6

New ModelResource:

```
class IssuerResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Issuer
```

New stack trace:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\threading.py", line 69, in run
    reraise(*_capture_exception())
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\_compat.py", line 54, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\threading.py", line 67, in run
    return old_run_func(self, *a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Prosy\Desktop\dalmore\dalmoreportal\misc\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from crowdfunding.submodels.issuer_model import Issuer
  File "C:\Users\Prosy\Desktop\dalmore\dalmoreportal\crowdfunding\submodels\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .issuer_model import *
  File "C:\Users\Prosy\Desktop\dalmore\dalmoreportal\crowdfunding\submodels\issuer_model.py", line 78, in <module>
    class IssuerResource(ModelResource):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 926, in __new__
    field = new_class.field_from_django_field(f.name, f,
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 1075, in field_from_django_field
    FieldWidget = cls.widget_from_django_field(django_field)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 1041, in widget_from_django_field
    result = getattr(cls, result)(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 1012, in get_m2m_widget
    model=get_related_model(field))
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 45, in get_related_model
    if hasattr(field, 'related_model'):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 95, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in `django-import-export-celery` 1.1.5 and later.

Equivalent code fix:

```py
class IssuerResource(ModelResource):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   # +
        kwargs.pop('export_job', None)     # +
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # +

    class Meta:
        model = Issuer
```

Reference: [django-import-export-celery@5fde9d0](https://github.com/auto-mat/django-import-export-celery/commit/5fde9d013839a0d7672bfd4de2abc24633cd9f8c)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce that. Can you move `IssuerResource` to crowdfunding/submodels/resources.py and do `from crowdfunding.submodels.resources import IssuerResource` in `def export_resource_classes(cls):` as suggested in [auto-mat/django-import-export-celery#19 (comment 640915636)](https://github.com/auto-mat/django-import-export-celery/issues/19#issuecomment-640915636)?

Comment: can I see the link to the sample repo of your app? I'll study what the difference is. Thanks

Comment: I just tried in an existing app, I don't have a public one. I can take a look at yours.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a migrate. Django doesn't recognize "export_job" until you make a migrate.